# matplotlib plot 3D scatter plot where one axis is time or date

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm having problems with plotting 3D data where one of the dimensions is a date. I am wondering how I can solve it because any solution I can come up with looks too complicated for such a common case problem.

My solution is to drop the date dimension and replace it with an integer. I'd like to map this integer back to the dates. Any ideas what the best way to do this?

The code below works, but please adjust N to a smaller number if you want.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 1000

bm = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.bdate_range(start='2012-01-01', periods=N, freq='B'), 
    data={x: np.random.randn(N) for x in range(1, 11)}
)

# Simulate some zeros
bm = pd.DataFrame(index=bm.index, columns=bm.columns, data=np.where(np.abs(bm.values) < 0.02, 0, bm.values))

# Set zeros to Nan so that I don't plot them
bm = bm.replace({0: np.nan})

# unstack dataframe
flat_bm = bm.reset_index(drop=True).unstack()  # DROP DATES AND REPLACE WITH INT
x = flat_bm.index.get_level_values(0)
y = flat_bm.index.get_level_values(1)
z = flat_bm.values


# Set up plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')

# plotting
ax.scatter(x, y, z, '.', c=flat_bm.values, cmap='Reds')
```

At the end, the plot has an integer instead of date labels.

Answer (score 2):

When you supply dates to `matplotlib`, it internally converts them to numbers using `date2num`. They are specific numbers where zero is 1970-01-01 00:00:00. You don't see the numbers as it formats the plot with text labels like month name, year, day of the week, etc.

In your case case, you need to manually convert the date to a number, create a plotting grid from that, and then after plotting reformat the numbers into meaningful date labels.

[image]

These are the manipulations I've performed:

```py
from matplotlib import dates as mdates

#Convert dates to numbers
date_as_num = mdates.date2num(bm.index)

#Grid for plotting
x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(date_as_num, bm.columns)

[plotting code here...]

# Format based on a layout you define:
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%Y-%b-%a'))
```

The first step is to convert the dates to numbers that `matplotlib.dates` can work with: `date_as_num = mdates.date2num(bm.index)`. It maps your dates to numbers, i.e. `date_as_num=[15341, ..., 15478]` which is simply the number of days since 1970-01-01.

You then create x and y grids for plotting the data. The data is shaped `100x10`, so the grids need to match that. `x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(date_as_num, bm.columns)` - this duplicates the x axis for each value of y (giving `x_grid`), and the y axis for each value of x (giving `y_grid`).

Finally, plot the data and then format the numerical date axis with meaningful date markers. Below I've formatted it as *year-month name-day name* (see [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for the various options): `ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%Y-%b-%a'))`.

Examples of other date formatting options:

```py
# AutoDateFormater, where locator= can be None, MonthLocator(), etc
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(mdates.MonthLocator()))

# ConciseDateFormatter can choose a clean and informative layout:
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator=None))
```

[List](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html#date-tick-locators) of available date locators (week, month, etc). Examples-based [reading](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#date-tick-labels) about date formatting using `matplotlib`.

---

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


N = 100

bm = pd.DataFrame(
    index=pd.bdate_range(start='2012-01-01', periods=N, freq='B'), 
    data={x: np.random.randn(N) for x in range(1, 11)}
)

# Simulate some zeros
bm = pd.DataFrame(index=bm.index, columns=bm.columns, data=np.where(np.abs(bm.values) < 0.02, 0, bm.values))

# Set zeros to Nan so that I don't plot them
bm = bm.replace({0: np.nan})

# Set up plot
fig = plt.figure(figsize = (15,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection ='3d')

#Dates to numbers, and create meshgrid
from matplotlib import dates as mdates
date_as_num = mdates.date2num(bm.index)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(date_as_num, bm.columns)

# plotting
ax.scatter(x_grid, y_grid, z, '.', c=flat_bm.values, cmap='Reds')
# Format based on a layout you define:
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(fmt='%Y-%b-%a'))

#Examples of alternative formatting options:
# AutoDateFormater, where locator= can be None, MonthLocator(), etc
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.AutoDateFormatter(mdates.MonthLocator()))
# ConciseDateFormatter can choose a clean and informative layout:
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator=None))
```